# how do I properly set the grid template areas?

Tags: css-grid

Can anyone pls explain to me why the third-row "content" is not displaying fully? I am new to using the grid template areas and couldn't figure out why the content row is not set to the maximum width and fully display on the screen like other rows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Exercise 1</title>
    <meta content="width=device-width", initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1
    name="viewport"/>
    
    <style>

    body{
        background-color: #444;
    }
    .container {
        display: grid;
        width: 90%;
        grid-template-columns: 300px 300px 300px;
        grid-template-rows: 100px 350px 100px 50px;
        grid-template-areas: 
        "hd hd hd hd"
        "feat feat feat feat"
        "con con con con"
        "ft ft ft ft";
        border: solid 2px rgb(247,182, 97);
    }
    .box {
        border: solid 1px red;
        background: #f8fa90;
    
    }
    .header{grid-area: hd;}
    .feature{grid-area: feat;}
    .content{grid-area: con; width: 100%;}
    .footer{grid-area: ft;}

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header box">Header</div>
        <div class="feature box">Feature Content</div>
        <div class="Content box">Content</div>
        <div class="footer box">footer</div>
    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2bw7Luzg/

Comment: The class name is "Content", the style is set to "content"

Comment: that solves the problem, thank you very much